# What is the best data structure for a map of 3 items

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's sayIi have the given values (Origin, Destiny, Distance):

```
A ~ B = 5
B ~ C = 10
A ~ C = 20
```

And I want to find the shortest way from A to C (in this case A->B, B->C).

What is the best data structure to store/search those values?

Comment: Use a tree or a graph, because this looks like a shortest-path problem, and use [`A*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) for fast search.

Comment: Graph's are pretty easy to represent in a `dict` -> `{node: {node: cost}}`, and one of the many [shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [networkx](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to represent your weighted graph, and then use 
[`dijkstra_path`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path) to find the shortest path.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a','b',weight=5)
G.add_edge('b','c',weight=10)
G.add_edge('a','c',weight=20)

print(nx.dijkstra_path(G,'a','c'))
```

This will give as output:

`['a', 'b', 'c']`

I think `dijkstra` algorithm is the best approach for shortest path problem from **one** vertex to all the others and as for complexity terms it is O(nlogn) where n is the number of the vertices.

Of course the shortest path algorithms work only when there are no negative circles (where shortest path problem has no meaning...).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!